# Is there a method to get a field in a collection by index without using Loop?

Tags: blueprism

I'm new to BluePrism, and

I have a collection named ToDate, and it had 1 column named `Column1`. I want to get the value of the second row, so I tried `[ToDate.Column1.Row(2)]`, but it didn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you provide code which you have worked with.

Comment: @Kalana Eranda Jayasuriya: In further edits, please refrain from putting program/tag names into code brackets ``. This is not necessary. The rest of your edit was good.

Answer (score 2):

It's a complicated thing to do in blueprism, actually.

You can try the following approaches:

1. Filter collection (using collection manipulation object), so that
   there's only one record, and then use [TemporaryCollection.Column1]
2. Use a page, that will loop through the collection and set the row
   that you'd like to have as a current row. Then you could use
   [ToDate.Column1].
3. Build a custom code. For example I have an action called vlookup,
   that mimicks the one from excel. Maybe that would be best here?

Answer (score 0):

i believe you would want to build your own object to do this specific function, it woul dbe something like this
where Coll is an input collection

```
If Not Coll.Columns.Contains(colname) Then
  Throw New ApplicationException(String.Format( _
   "The collection does not contain a field " & _
   "with the name '{0}'", colname))
End If


groups = New DataTable()
groups.Columns.Add("Group", GetType(String))

For Each row as DataRow in coll.Rows

  Dim store as String = CStr(row(colname))

  If store <> NULL Then
    For i as Integer = 1 to m.Groups.Count-1
      If i = 2
      groups.Rows.Add(New Object() {store.Value})
      break
      End If

    Next
    Return
  End If

Next
```

if you have multi column collections you would need to nest this for i loop in for each column loop as well to grab other values. Code written from memory will likely  not compile but mostly it should be there to fulfill your needs. this way you create an action with inputs and the output would be a collections specific row you are looking for.